# How to rename string values of a specific column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column of countries in my data set and I'd like to rename all UK countries in the column as "UK" i.e. I have:

'United Kingdom', 'Great Britain', 'England & Wales', 'Northern Ireland', 'Wales', 'England',  'Uk'

and I'd like to label them all under one name. Anyway I could do this?

Comment: make a dictionary and replace:-> `l = ['United Kingdom', 'Great Britain', 'England & Wales', 'Northern Ireland', 'Wales', 'England', 'Uk']` , and `df['col_of_countries'] = df['col_of_countries'].replace({i:"UK" for i in l})` something like this, or `series.str.replace` with `.join`. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to replace values from a list:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['United Kingdom', 'Great Britain', 'France', 'Belgium', 
                               'England & Wales', 'Poland', 'Northern Ireland', 'Wales', 
                               'England', 'Uk']})

print(df)

             country
0     United Kingdom
1      Great Britain
2             France
3            Belgium
4    England & Wales
5             Poland
6   Northern Ireland
7              Wales
8            England
9                 Uk
```

**Solution:**

```
names_list = ['United Kingdom', 'Great Britain', 'England & Wales', 
              'Northern Ireland', 'Wales', 'England', 'Uk']

df['country'] = ['UK' if x in names_list else x for x in df['country']]
```

**Output:**

```
    country
0        UK
1        UK
2    France
3   Belgium
4        UK
5    Poland
6        UK
7        UK
8        UK
9        UK
```